# How to run Arduino 1.0.6 on OS X 10.10 with Java 7 or 8 already installed

Tags: arduino-ide, osx

On a new Mac (running OS X 10.10) with Java 7 or 8 already installed (for other development), how can I run the Arduino 1.0.6 IDE (which seems to be required for the LightBlue Bean BLE Arduino device), which seems to require using a very old Java 6 installer from Apple?

Is there a way to install multiple versions of Java without breaking any of them?  Or is there a way to use the Arduino 1.0.x IDE with a newer version of Java?

Or should I re-ask this question over at the apple.stackexchange.com site?

Comment: I think they have a special version of the IDE. https://punchthrough.com/bean/getting-started-osx/ . What error do you get when you run the app?

Comment: You can call `java` specifying each and every `.jar` to its `-cp` (classpath) parameter.
Sure you can't just use the latest 1.6.1? Or the current nightly, soon to become 1.6.2, which bundles java 8?

Comment: Reportedly the LightBlue SDK installation currently destroys an Arduino 1.6.x IDE.